# What is this sweet, thick, soy-sauce-like condiment in China?

Tags: china, food-and-drink, identify-this, beijing

In Beijing, on two occasions, I was served a sauce I couldn't identify.

[image]

Visually it looks like soy sauce but it's much thicker and stickier. It tastes soy-ish, but sweeter, maybe malty in some way. Definitely has fermented aspects. I asked someone who lives elsewhere in Asia and he said "sweet sauce" which isn't helpful. During the dinner where I took this picture, I asked my "handler" who said "we just call it sauce" which again wasn't helpful.

Does it have a name outside China? Is this something I could buy, as you can buy oyster sauce, hoisin sauce etc, if only I knew its name? It was really good.

Comment: Dark Soy Sauce.

Answer (score 4):

It could be 甜面酱/甜酱 or [sweet bean sauce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_bean_sauce) aka sweet flour sauce or just sweet sauce. You can probably find it in a Chinese supermarket under one of those names.

Comment: interesting, Wikipedia says "sweet bean sauce may be used in dishes such as Peking Duck" and that was in fact the second occasion on which I had it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Indonesian sauce called *kecap manis* that sounds exactly the way you describe. It is also common outside of Indonesia, including China and South East Asia.

That may not be what you had. If it was *very* sticky, the here in Ecuador they call it Eel Sauce which is mostly soy sauce with lots and lots of sugar. Another possibility is a variant on Hoisin sauce which has a more beany taste but is usually more brown rather than almost black like the one you show.

Comment: My Singapore contact said their name for it literally means "sweet sauce" and I note that kecap manis in Indonesian translates to "sweet soy sauce" so you may have a winner. Now what would kecap manis be called in a North American grocery store?

Comment: In Ecuador its just *salsa china dulce* which means sweet Chinese sauce but in Canada I found it actually labelled Kecap Manis.

Comment: While the description matches, *kecap manis* is an Indonesian sauce and would not be used by a Chinese restaurant in Beijing.

Comment: Of course, although the contents no longer match, _kecap_ is the origin of _ketchup_ (also spelled _catsup_ in English)

Comment: In fact the *c* in *kecap* is pronounced *tch* as in ketchup which is why for a while I had trouble asking for *kecap manis*!

Comment: @KateGregory would it be hoisin sauce?